# How can I simplify this regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

The format I'm trying to match is:

```
# (Apple push notification codes)
"11a735e9 9f696c2f 700b2700 728042c6 137eeb7a 8442c27d 40e59d9e 3c7e0de7"
```

The simplest expression I can think of is: `/((\w{8}\s){7}\w{8})/i`

Can anyone think of a simpler one?

(I'm using Ruby regular expressions)

UPDATE - thanks to user1096188, I've removed \d - this is included in \w

Comment: \w captures both letters and digits, you don't need [\w\d]

Comment: You don't need the i at the end either since \w matches upper and lower case letters.

Comment: You can add ?: in the parentheses so it won't capture backreferences. Also, don't you need the "^" and "$" ?

Comment: Yes - strictly speaking. This is the best I have now:

`/^(\w{8}(\s|$)){8}/`

Seems to work a treat :)

Comment: You could still use `\x` instead of `\w` to restrict the permitted range to hex digits only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect a word boundary using `\b`, and use `(?:` to prevent capturing groups

```
/(?:\w{8}\b\s?){8}/
```

Comment: minus the i `/(?:\w{8}\b\s?){8}/` :)

Comment: Thanks, the i is not necessary, since \w matches any case. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this if the end of the match is the end of the whole string.
`(\w{8}(:?\s|$)){7}`

Comment: the Ruby scan() and match() methods return nested arrays when comparing a Regex with parenthesis. I was hoping for something simpler - regexes are not my forte though and I've already learned 3 or 4 things from this Q - that's why I asked :)

Comment: In Ruby regexps, `$` is **not** the end of the string but the end of a line. The end of string is `\z`. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
> "11a735e9 9f696c2f 700b2700 728042c6 137eeb7a 8442c27d 40e59d9e 3c7e0de7".match(/((\w{8}\s)+)/)
> $&
 => "11a735e9 9f696c2f 700b2700 728042c6 137eeb7a 8442c27d 40e59d9e 3c7e0de7"
```

Comment: This would also match `"11a735e99f696c2f700b2700728042c6137eeb7a8442c27d40e59d9e3c7e0de7"` - the spaces are not optional

Answer (score 0):

Taking @zapthedingbat's solution one stage further, it looks like the code only contains hexadecimal characters (0-9 and a-f) and spaces. So you could possibly sacrifice a little simplicity for accuracy.

I'm making an assumption, but I suspect letters g to z are invalid.
If the format is hexadecimal only (you should check Apple's documentation to be sure), a tighter match would be:

```
/(?:[0-9a-f]{8}\b\s?){8}/
```

**EDIT**

In fact, in Ruby, it looks like you should be able to do:

```
/(?:\h{8}\b\s?){8}/
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm not sure if it's hex or just a random string... I'll check that though